# How to Map Triggers For Run Away in Final Fantasy 7?

Tags: pc, final-fantasy-7

I'm using a gamepad for FF7 on PC and no matter what I've tried, I can't map the triggers on my gamepad to Page Up and Page Down so I can run away! Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Comment: Are you using any mapping software? Personally I find running a PSX game in ePSXe to be much better than playing its PC port precisely because i don't have to deal with ancient software's bugs.

Comment: I am not using any mapping software. I've seen people recommend Xpadder, worth a shot?

Comment: Yeah, Xpadder should work.

Comment: @kotekzot - There is a modern version of this port, though, and the PC version of FF7 is unique anyway in that it fixed a bunch of localization errors from the PSX version.

Comment: I also recommend XPadder. Its well worth the money and you should never have problems mapping controllers again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [JoyToKey](http://joytokey.net/) for solve this problem. This program is used for mapping the keys into joypad buttons.

Answer (score 0):

FF7 PC has native gamepad support for PlayStation style controllers(DS1, PS pad, ETC.).  My sister has had very little trouble mapping several of these onto the game in fact it sees these automatically.  I haven't messed with the Xbox 360 controller for windows but I've had trouble mapping my dual shock clone onto TF2(Still don't have this right).

The main thing I've heard is the with the official drivers the triggers on a 360 controller don't seem to function.  You could try these and see if it makes a difference.  Also Xpadder works great with certain games...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an xbox 360 controller that you are using, I have found this guide on Steam to be the best solution:

[Xbox 360 Controller Fix](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=179295659)

It does however require that you are using the English Steam version of FF7.

Comment: Please don't post just a link; if the link target disappears or is moved, your answer is useless. Please summarize the important parts.